# Replace host in all URLs in a string - nodejs

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, string, url

I have following string:

```
{
   "auth" : {
     "login" : "http://123.123.11.22:85/auth/signin",
     "resetpass" : "http://123.123.22.33:85/auth/resetpass",
     "profile" : "http://123.123.33.44:85/auth/profile"
   }
}
```

I need to replace all IP addresses with my host name to get following output:

```
{
   "auth" : {
      "login" : "http://mydomain:85/auth/signin",
      "resetpass" : "http://mydomain:85/auth/resetpass",
      "profile" : "http://mydomain:85/auth/profile"
   }
}
```

I can convert this string to object, iterate through properties, split and rejoin to form the URL. I'm looking for the best practice to achieve this using regex.

I expect something like

```
var newUrl = text.replace( /someRegex/gi, 'mydomain');
```

Comment: Bad but short. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(thatObject).replace(/someRegex/gi, 'myDomain'))`

Comment: I know how to stringify. I need that regex.

Comment: From google search http://www.regextester.com/22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)(?=:\d+)` and replacing the captured group will work for you.

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/qXcIzI/2)

Comment: Works like a charm. in my case: `var result = data.replace(/((?:\d+.){3}\d+)(?=:\d+)/g, host);`